# How to loop through text of a dictionary that has a single value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble with a dictionary that contains one single value. This single value is text fashioned the following way:

```
    dict_values([{'top':                       query  value
0      the urban dictionary    100
1                definition     50
2    urban dictionary words     12
3    urban dictionary names     10
4     word urban dictionary     10
5          urban outfitters      9
6     thot urban dictionary      8
7      dog urban dictionary      6
8      cap urban dictionary      6
9     urban dictionary yeet      6
10                     yeet      6
11     top urban dictionary      5
12    stan urban dictionary      4
13  urban dictionary boomer      4
14                   boomer      4
15    fomo urban dictionary      4
16    urban dictionary drip      4
17     smh urban dictionary      4
18                      smh      4
19                urban air      3
20     tea urban dictionary      3
21   green urban dictionary      3
22     bet urban dictionary      3
23                     vsco      3
24    goat urban dictionary      3
```

I want to convert that dictionary into a data frame with three columns - index, query and popularity. Any idea how to do that?

Here is the code to get the dictionary:

```
!pip install pytrends
import pandas as pd                        
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
ytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['urban dictionary'],timeframe='2019-01-01 2019-12-31')
related_queries = pytrend.related_queries()
related_queries.values()
```

Cheers,

edit: output needs to be a dataframe, not dictionary

Comment: Can you post that dictionary as valid python. It's really hard to know what you are starting with. Is that big value a single formatted string?

Comment: If the value is text, you'll have to parse it somehow, perhaps with the `re` regular expression library. Please edit you question and show the representation of the text value if you want a better answer — try using somethin like `print(repr(value))` to get this.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have "columns".  Are you sure you want it to be a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

```
data2 = dict(re.findall("\s*([a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z])\s{2,}(\d+)",data['top']))
```

I guess would get you pretty close (the digits are strings in the result...)

as an aside though i would hazard a guess that your data['top'] is actually a dataframe and not a string (based on the representation printed)

in which case you can do `data['top']['query']` and that would print that whole column , or do `data['top'][data['top']['query'] == 'urban outfitters']` to see just the matching row

Comment: Well it looks like a dataframe but it's actually a dictionary value... So the last chunk of code doesn't work because dictionary values are not subscriptable...

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import List, NamedTuple


class Entry(NamedTuple):
    index: int
    query: str
    popularity: int


def format_dictionary_text(text: str) -> List[Entry]:
    entries: List[Entry] = []
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        tokens = line.split()
        if len(tokens) < 3:
            continue  # "query value" garbage at top?
        entries.append(Entry(
            int(tokens[0]),
            " ".join(tokens[1:-1]),
            int(tokens[-1])
        ))
    return entries


text = """             query value
0      the urban dictionary    100
1                definition     50
2    urban dictionary words     12
3    urban dictionary names     10
4     word urban dictionary     10
5          urban outfitters      9
6     thot urban dictionary      8
7      dog urban dictionary      6
8      cap urban dictionary      6
9     urban dictionary yeet      6
10                     yeet      6
11     top urban dictionary      5
12    stan urban dictionary      4
13  urban dictionary boomer      4
14                   boomer      4
15    fomo urban dictionary      4
16    urban dictionary drip      4
17     smh urban dictionary      4
18                      smh      4
19                urban air      3
20     tea urban dictionary      3
21   green urban dictionary      3
22     bet urban dictionary      3
23                     vsco      3
24    goat urban dictionary      3
"""

print(format_dictionary_text(text))
```

A list of `NamedTuple`s seems like the most convenient representation to me, but it should be straightforward to convert this to some kind of dict if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! Where does format_dictionary_text stores its results?

Comment: It doesn't store it anywhere, it `return`s it.  Do something like `entries = format_dictionary_text(my_text)`.